# CSS multi-row table without "display: table-row"

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need to create a multi-row table without using `display: table-row`.

Because it is formatted from a template, and it is impossible to insert "row" code between "some" items. All items are the same.

What I need: 3 columns and 3 rows, and the same height for all columns.

If I remove `float: left` then all items is displayed in one row. With it, they all have different height.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

p {
  background: #eeeeee;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ca4deko/

Comment: What is the question? What problem(s) are you facing while doing this? SO is not a platform to provide you code. It is meant for solving problems.

Comment: so no question but a task to be done ?

Comment: This is not a table. This is a list. Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ykdzqacr/) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `display: flex`

http://jsfiddle.net/dnomLjue/1/

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 33%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

p {
  background: #eeeeee;
  margin: 2px;
  height: calc( 100% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ddd<br>ddd</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```